# Differentiate between SAML verified and other apps on okta api

Tags: get, postman, okta, okta-api

How to differentiate between SAML verified and other apps on okta api. Is it possible to achieve this via filter or we have to do some offline processing on responses of all apps received.
I am trying to achieve the above query using get request on postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no standard filter provided by okta , 
you can get all app responses from okta then filter apps from received jsonArray with signOnMode as SAML_2_0.